# Table para Excel demorando demais

Tags: php, html5, microsoft-excel, revisão-de-código

Bom , tenho uma consulta no banco de dados , que me retorna a depender dessa consulta coisa de 5k linhas a 30k linhas , estou gerando já em excel através do código abaixo , contudo quando me traz cerca de mais de 5k de informações , ele demora muito para carregar . Alguém poderia ajudar em relação ao código ou outra forma de gerar o excel ?

```
excel.php:


<?php
   $file = 'planilha.xls';
   header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
   header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file}\"" );
   header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );
?>
<?php
    define('DB_HOST'        , "");
    define('DB_USER'        , "");
    define('DB_PASSWORD'    , "");
    define('DB_NAME'        , "");
    define('DB_DRIVER'      , "sqlsrv");

    require_once "Conexao.php";

try{
  //inicia a conexao
   $Conexao     = Conexao::getConnection();

   $filial1 = $_POST[];
   $filial2 = $_POST[];
   $data_inicial = $_POST[_];
   $data_final = $_POST[];



  //faz a consulta na tabela procurando palavras do form
   $query       = $Conexao->query (" EXECUCAO DA MINHA PROCEDURE ");
   $teste       = $query->fetchAll();

  }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
?>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center><b></b></center>
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        foreach($teste as $CLIENTE) {
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE['']; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <?php echo $CLIENTE[]; ?>
                    </center>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Normalmente revisões de códigos precisam ser mais específicas e requerem mais detalhes.

Comment: No caso , eu apresentei o meu código de como estou gerando o Excel , minha duvida está na parte de como poderia melhorar esse código em especifico . Descrevi meu código inteiro e expliquei o motivo de está realizando uma possível melhora .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou adicionar algumas considerações, mas dificilmente será uma resposta específica ao seu problema.

Existem diversas formas de "atacar" esse problema, a primeira delas é aumentar os recursos da maquina de forma que o script gere o conteúdo de forma mais rápida, essa solução é relativamente fácil, porém dificilmente escalável, vai chegar uma hora que não vai existir mais máquina única capaz de gerar o conteúdo.

A segunda forma é agendar a criação da tabela e informar ao usuário quando a mesma estiver pronta, ou seja, o usuário em vez de clicar em gerar a tabela e esperar a tabela ficar pronta, ele passaria a solicitar (por meio de um botão ou algo) e seu sistema colocaria a criação em background para ser executada no tempo necessário, quando o arquivo estiver pronto você informa ao usuário por email ou algum outro mecanismo.

Se você precisa do conteúdo de forma periódica, pode fazer um cronjob para executar o script durante a noite ou algum horário que o servidor recebe menos carga, armazenando o resultado e fornecendo o arquivo já computado quando solicitado.

Uma última consideração, é a query SQL em si, que na pergunta foi omitida, talvez seja legal você verificar quanto tempo ela demora a ser executada, talvez o problema nem seje realmente no PHP.

Comment: $query       = $Conexao->query ("EXEC procedure '$x,'$y','$z','$fw' "); essa é a minha query .